# Nullable boolean value with property

Tags: c#, null

Our Sonar code analysis server tells me

> Boolean literals should not be redundant. Redundant Boolean literals
>   should be removed from expressions to improve readability. Tag:
>   Clumsy

and categorizes it as a minor bug.

Is this an error in the associated Sonar/FXCop C# rule (maybe it cannot handle nullable types?!) or is this really clumsy?

Note: `createMissing` is a value which comes from a datastore (Edit: in this implementation it is parsed from a XML document) where null is a valid value (because the attribute is not mandatory) and in my business logic null means equals false).

```
[XmlIgnore]
private bool? createMissing = null;

[XmlAttribute("createMissing")]
public bool CreateMissing
{
    get
    {
        return createMissing.HasValue ? createMissing.Value : false;
    }

    set
    {
        createMissing = value;
    }
}

public bool ShouldSerializeCreateMissing()
{
    return createMissing.HasValue;
}
```

Comment: `Nullable<T>` has a method called `GetValueOrDefault` which is the equivalent of your code as `false` is `default(bool)`.

Comment: This question lacks context. Could you show us where you load the data from the datastore, so that we can better advise you?

Comment: I've added the missing context (meta: but was this really worth a downvote?! :D)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about redundant, but this:

```
return createMissing.HasValue ? createMissing.Value : false;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
return createMissing ?? false;
```

This doesn't look like there's any redundancy to me.

Comment: Oh yes thats better. ?? operator is new in C# 6 right?

Comment: @PhilipC - no it's not. The Null Coalescing Operator is ancient. The Null *Propagation* Operator is the new one.

Comment: @RobH You're quite right - I was getting it mixed up with the Null Propagation Operator. The Null Coalescing Operator was introduced alongside nullable types [in C# 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_2.0#Null-coalescing_operator). I'll get rid of my earlier comment to remove the incorrect information.

Answer (score 3):

Although Philip C has provided one option, I'd just like to show a couple of others for completeness.

My suggestion from the comments:

```
public bool CreateMissing
{
    get
    {
        return createMissing.GetValueOrDefault();
    }
    set
    {
        createMissing = value;
    }
}
```

I personally think this makes the most sense.

Another option would simply be:

```
return createMissing.HasValue && createMissing.Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

> Boolean literals should not be redundant

a redundant statement is something that doesn't add anything. Something like:

```
if(booleanVariable == true)
```

or

```
numericValue + 0
```

or

```
numericValue * 1
```

you get the idea.

In your case, you use the ternary operator:

```
condition ? value : false;
```

Notice that `condition` is evaluated to a boolean value already.

The problem is that the usual solution of simply omitting the redundant stuff doesn't work in your situation. In the above examples, simply remove `==true`, `+ 0` and `* 1`. In your case there's no such obvious thing to remove.

One could be tempted to simply return the `condition` part like so:

```
get
{
    return createMissing;
}
```

But that doesn't work because [`bool?` cannot be converted to `bool`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22680505/4347580) implicitly. So what now?

You have to make a decision on what should happen when the value is `null`. In a way, the ternary operator does this, but (and this is why Sonar tags this as *clumsy*) in a really clumsy way.

Try something like:

```
get
{
    return createMissing == true;
}
```

*Wait a second, that's one of the examples of redundant code this answer started with! Wtf?*

No, it's not. The difference is subtle, but important: this is not a boolean variable. It's a `bool?`. It has 3 states, hence checking for equality against `true` is like checking `numericValue == 5`, which is perfectly valid.

`bool?` is like a numeric value of a 2 bit system, except that one of the 4 possible values is not available whatsoever.

Not applicable to your situation, but if you wanted to evaluate both  `null` and `true` to `true`, try this code:

```
get
{
    return createMissing != false;
}
```